# How to open a webview in reading view ? UWP

Tags: c#, windows, webview, win-universal-app, uwp

**I have a FeedReader app and I would like my pages open in reading view ( feature from IE 11 , EDGE ) .as an example The news app in windows 10 uses this feature and all news descriptions are in reading view .** is it possible ?

Reading View example (Screenshot)  :

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/733596

News app reading view example (Screenshot) :

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/733599

Thanks in advance .

Comment: your links dosen't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases the content of the web page is extracted and shown with custom styling.

To get the same result you can use something like [DIFFBOT](http://www.diffbot.com/) (which I think is used in the News app) or [Embedly](http://embed.ly/) which is cheaper, and get the content parsed and returned nice and structured. After that you'll have to style it yourself.

You can style it by "converting" it from HTML and show it in a `TextBlock`, or you can show it in a `WebView`.

**EDIT:**
You can use something like [HtmlUtilities.ConvertToText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.html.htmlutilities.converttotext.aspx) to get the text from the HTML. I think you can convert one section at a time, that way you can style headers and such.

Comment: First Thank u , I think the best way is converting html . Do you know Any useful link for how to doing this?